Spectrum of $S_r$ and $S_l$ on $\ell _2 (\mathbb{Z})$

Calculate the spectrum of $S_r$ and $S_l$ on $\ell _2 (\mathbb{Z})$

I want to make sure my solution is correct:
$\sigma _r (S_r)$: we need $S_r (a_n) = \lambda (a_n)$ and so we get for every $n=: a_{n+1} =\lambda a_n$ and so $a_n = a_0\cdot \lambda^n$ but then $a_n \notin \ell _2 (\mathbb{Z})$.
So $\sigma _r (S_r)=\emptyset$.
$\sigma _c (S_r)$: Let there be $(b_n) \in \ell _2 (\mathbb{Z})$. Let $\epsilon >0$ so we know there exists $N>0$ s.t $\sum _{|n|>N} |b_n|^2<\epsilon$. Now define $a_n$ s.t
$$\forall n: |n|<N     \ \ \ \ \ a_{n+1} -\lambda a_n =b_n$$
And $0$ otherwise.
This is $n$ linear equations with $n+2$ variables. And so we get:
$$\|({S_r}-\lambda I)(a_n)-b_n\|=\sum _{|n|>N} |b_n|^2<\epsilon$$ and $(a_n)\in \ell _2 (\mathbb{Z})$. so we get $\overline{Im(S_r -\lambda I)}=\ell _2 (\mathbb{Z})$.
And so $\sigma _c (S_r)=\{\lambda | |\lambda| \leq 1\}$ (I did not so but $\|S_r -\lambda I\|=1$ and so $\sigma(S_r -\lambda I)$ contain only $\lambda$ with norm less then $1$.

Did you mean to write $\color{red}N$ linear equations with $\color{red}N+2$ variables?

Don't forget to write \{...\} because {} won't be printed (=:

Yes, correct and thank you :)
But I still think the proof is correct
